# How to close the prefetch of cache in windows?

Tags: c++, windows, caching, prefetch

In a C/C++ program, how to close the prefetch of each core in the Windows system?

Comment: Hmm ... might use better wording here. Do you mean disabling prefetch from particular addresses? Something else? What are you trying to accomplish?

Answer (score 3):

There is a Windows API call FlushInstructionCache()

Perhaps this is what you need? It is typically used by self modifying code to make sure changes to code in the RAM are visible to the processor.

Answer (score 0):

I have seen this trick mentioned in some code, although I am not 100% sure if this trick is what you're looking for, however, the code was this

```
Sleep(0);
```

By using `Sleep(0)`, you are clearing the CPU instructions and cause a context switch... Now you did say 'for each core', I do not think you can explicitly select a core to do that as how do you know which core is running the code that is need of a closing the pre-fetching of the cache....

Comment: `Sleep()` does not guarantee a context switch. Also context switch is sort of a brutal way to stop prefetching.

Comment: @Nikolai: Ahhh...k.... no prob so....I wasn't really sure....thanks for your input! :)